# How to forbid the user to interact with Google maps(android)?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to disable all gestures. How to do it?

Comment: Put a view on it to steal all the touch events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable all the gestures doing

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```